# How to fix error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol when use git clone

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssl, tfs, clone

Im using Windows 10 and VS2017, and tried to clone a TFSgit repository.

The steps to access the repository are:

1. Connect to VPN server throught Cisco AnyConnect;
2. Connect to the TFS;
3. Clone the repository that I have access with my user;

That been said, when I choose one os the projects and try to clone(via VS, via terminal, via git bash, etc) I get this error everytime:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://server:1234/tfs/project/_git/core': error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

And I'm kinda confusing because the server does not have a SSL certificate, which means that it should not try to communicate with a https protocol, and even if I try to force clone(git clone http://...), the same error pops out

I already tried to reinstall git, and download it again to make sure that I use the lastest version, tried to reinstall VS

I hoping to find a solution that not involves formating the machine

edit: Since the problem was kinda critical, I have formated the machine and it solve the question, but if someone has an answer to this, I would appreciate

Comment: I once had a similar problem, where I yanked the remote's url and pasted into the terminal, but the yanked url had a "strange" character in the front of the url, have you tried manually typing the url into the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and still does not worked